# Undistort image containing planar object of known dimensions using openCV python

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, camera-calibration

I have the following image extracted from a video:

[image]
It is a field hockey pitch with standard dimensions (91.4m x 55m). I can even map all lines intersections if necessary.

The image is distorded. I'd like to undistord it using openCV.

I thought something similar to cv2.FindChessBoardCorners() followed by CalibrateCamera() (i.e. using standard ChessBoard Calibration techniques) could be possible to use since I known the dimensions of the field. More exactly, I tried to use the tutorial from there: https://medium.com/@kennethjiang/calibrate-fisheye-lens-using-opencv-333b05afa0b0

So, how can I undistord this image, provided that I precisely known the dimensions of the pitch?

Comment: What's your question? You seem to have forgotten to ask one.

Comment: @DanMašek how can I undistord this image, provided that I precisely known the dimensions of the pitch?

Comment: Have you already tried some calibration that based on your knowledge about the pitch?

Comment: @fana I precisely don't know how to do that. All the literature I can find is based on a chessboard calibration

Answer (score 0):

I guess there are 2 possible directions.

### 1. Do Camera Calibration

Chessboard pattern is often used for calibration, but of course other patterns may be used.
What we need is constraints that we can use for optimization.

Therefore, the geometric knowledges of the pitch you have also may be able to used.
e.g. some known positions, some straight lines may be able to used as the constraints.

However, in general, we have to used many number of images to obtain good accuracy.
It is important that the constraints are distributed over the entire field of view and that the distribution is not extremely biased.
Therefore, if only one or a few images can be used, or if it is not possible to change the camera pose to capture various images, the accuracy of the calibration results cannot be expected.
(In the first place, if such work can be performed, there is no need to insist on using pitch images...)

### 2. Some Morphing like way.

You know the real shape of the pitch, so, for some points, you can do "manual undistortion".
When you can give the movement from the position in the original image to in undistorted image to a point, the amount of movement that should be given to the points around it should also be a similar value.
So, "interpolate the movement" can be conceivable.

Although this method is simple, the results may be unsatisfactory.
There is also the problem of what to do with the outside of the pitch.